# como construir essa requisição PHP em Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, libcurl

```
 $msec = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
 $apiId = 'bd443f00-092c-4436-92a4-a704ef679e24';
 $apiSecret = 'api_secret_key';
 $method = 'account';
 $req = json_encode(array(
  'ts' => $msec));

 $sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $method.$req, $apiSecret);
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://payeer.com/api/trade/".$method);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "API-ID: ".$apiId,
  "API-SIGN: ".$sign));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($response, true));
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar o Fetch API e o WebCrypto. Entretanto, note que "Javascript" é muito amplo e nem sempre essas APIs estão disponíveis. Estou assumindo que quer utilizar num navegador ou num ambiente onde tenha acesso à todas as WebAPI.

*Isso assume que a codificação padrão é UTF-8.*

---

```
var msec = Math.round(performance.timing.navigationStart + performance.now()); // Não dá pra saber o que quer com isso.

var apiId = 'bd443f00-092c-4436-92a4-a704ef679e24';
var req = JSON.stringify({'ts': msec});
var method = 'account';
var apiSecret = new Uint8Array(32);  // Isso deve ser Uint8Array, decodificado se for hex.

var enc = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
var algo = {name: "HMAC", hash: {name: "SHA-256"}};


let sign = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", apiSecret, algo, false, ["sign", "verify"]).then(function(key) {
    return window.crypto.subtle.sign("HMAC", key, enc.encode(method+req)).then(function(s) {
        return [...new Uint8Array(s)].map(function(b) { return b.toString (16).padStart (2, "0") }).join ("");
    });
});


fetch("https://payeer.com/api/trade/" + method, {
  body: req,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "API-ID": apiId,
    "API-SIGN:": sign,
  },
  method: "POST"
})
```

---

O `microtime` deve ser mais equivalente ao Performance API (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Performance).

O `req` é um JSON, então usa o JSON.stringify, para criar uma string usando os objetos.

O `enc` é necessário para o WebCrypto, já que ele usa bytes e não textos, e a codificação de textos pode variar.

O `sign` utiliza o WebCrypto (veja mais em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API). *A API do WebCrypto é uma das coisas mais horrorosas do Javascript.* Mas, primeiro, você deve importar a chave, e a chave deve ser bytes. Então se sua chave é um HEX e precisa ser passado para bytes, faça isso antes. A sua chave então é usada para criar uma chave no contexto do Javascript, usando o `importKey`. Então, depois, essa chave é usada para assinar usando o HMAC. Como a representação é em bytes, a codificação usada importa, e precisamos codificar para UTF-8. Depois, convertemos o resultado para HEX, que é o equivalente do PHP.

O `fetch` é usado para fazer a requisição, de modo mais parecido com o curl, pode ver mais sobre as opções em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API.